# How can we update apps in Office 365

Tags: office-365, nintex

How can we update the apps in Office 365? 
For instance, I have nintex added in my site collection, but I don't see any update option in the app. But when I open Nintex workflows, it keeps saying that I need to update the app

Can we uninstall and reinstall the Nintex app? will it affect the existing workflows?

Answer (score 1):

Below should work.

Are you using modern experience, You will not see update link like the following in modern site mode.

So in modern sites, you cannot update the app as easily. The best way is to use the link in the bottom left corner of the site page to "Switch to classic mode". Then you can easily click the Update link and follow the steps from the original document.

Reference link - https://community.nintex.com/t5/Community-Blogs/Manually-Update-O365-Apps/ba-p/76694

Hope this helps..!!!

Comment: The problem is, I don't get the "Get It" option. I am only seeing update button and when I click on it, it doesn't show the get it option

Comment: Did you check app version in app catalog and one in your site collection?